# Not able to call data-role="dialog"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have a single html page in which i use two  one is for data-role="page" and another is for data-role="dialog".
on my page div i have a button and from this button click i wanted to call div dialog.here is my example---

```
<html>
<body>
<div  data-role="page"
   data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="d">

          <div data-role="fieldcontain" align="vertical">
       <input type="reset" data-role="button" value="ok"
                           id="okButton">

              </div>
  $("#okButton").click(function ()
  {
                      $.mobile.changePage("#myDialog");   
  });
   </div>

<div id="myDialog" data-role="dialog" data-theme="b" >



   <div data-role="content">

       <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
       <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Add Margin" id="addmargin">
       <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="CTD" id="ctd">
       <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Square Off" id="squareoff">
       <input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Change Sqr.Off Mode" id="changeSqrMode">
              </div>

   </div>
```

Above code works fine But If I want to call Dialog on table row click then it is not called.  here is my table row click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#tableId tr td").live("click",function(e)
        {    
                var newrow = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());  


                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                alert("after e.stopImmediatePropagation");

                alert("Before  myDialog");              
                $.mobile.changePage('#myDialog');


        });


    </script>
```

here Before myDialog alert display but $.mobile.changePage('#myDialog'); not executed, or myDialog not displayed.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.mobile.changePage($('#myDialog'))`

Comment: using changePages it gives me error as : TypeError: Result of expression 'toPage.data( "page" )' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:2843

Comment: The error suggests that jQM can't find your dialog with the selector. Could you post the entire file you are trying to run, or maybe a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?